# Proving Euler's formula using infinity sums

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I want to prove $e^{i x} = \cos x + i \sin x$.

Proof:

$$e^{i x } = \sum \frac{x^{n} i^{n}  }{n!} 
= -i\sum_{\textrm{odd}} (-1)^{n} \frac{x^{2n+1}  }{(2n+1)!} + \sum_{\textrm{even}} (-1)^{n} \frac{x^{(2n)!}  }{(2n)!} $$

and this should give the Taylor series for $\sin$ and $\cos$. Is this argument valid?

Comment: The identity simply isn't true. You maybe meant $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$?

Comment: It should not be $-i\Sigma _ odd$. It should be +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically yes.

To be strict you can only reorder series if the convergence is absolute. To show that's the case you only have to consider the series for $e^{|x|}$, eventually the growth of the $n!$ will out-pace the growth of the $|x|^n$ by a factor and the terms will eventually shrink more than exponentially.

Comment: So one need to prove that the serie is absolute convergent. Is there a theorem that justify this? So one only need to prove that $\mid x \mid ^{n} / n!$ goes to zero for n going to infinity. Should I use L'Hospital to prove this or a epsilon-delta method?

Comment: @OlePetersen It's a well known fact that you can reorder an infinite sum if and only if it's absolutely convergent (but the fact that you can reorder an absolutely convergent series doesn't seem to be a named theorem). It doesn't suffice that $|x|^n/n!$ goes to zero, it has to do that quickly enough, but you have if $n>2|x|$ that the ratio between consecutive terms is less that $1/2$ and that means that $|x|^n/n! < C2^{-n}$ for some constant $C$ (which may depend on $x$).

Comment: I know that there exit a $n \in N$ so that $n > 2 \mid x \mid$ for $x \in Z$. I don't exactly understand "that the ratio between consecutive terms is less that $1/2$" ?

Comment: @OlePetersen It means that if $n>2|x|$ you would have the ratio between ${|x|^n\overn!}$ and ${|x|^{n+1}\over (n+1)!}$ being ${|x|\over(n+1)}<{1\over2}$. This means that after that the terms falls fast enough to make the series absolutely convergent (since for every $j>n$ you have ${|x|^j\over j!} < {|x|^n\over n!}2^{n-j}$).

Comment: I now see that the series is absolutely convergent still I don't see why it's necessary it needs to be fast ?